# MariaDB create stored procedure syntax error

Tags: mariadb

I feel like such a noob for asking this, but I can't for the life of me figure this one out. I'm trying to create a stored procedure here:

```
create or replace procedure add_cart(@user_id int, @product_id int, @quantity int)
begin
    declare cart_id int;
    start transaction;
    select id into cart_id from carts where user_id = @user_id;

    if cart_id is null then
        insert into carts (user_id, updated_at, inserted_at) values (@user_id, now(), now());
        select id into cart_id from carts where user_id = @user_id;
    end if;

    insert into cart_products (cart_id, product_id, quantity) values (cart_id, @product_id, @quantity);

    commit;
end
```

But I keep getting this `SyntaxError`:

```
[2022-06-14 10:29:29] [42000][1064] (conn=12) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@user_id int, @product_id int, @quantity int)
[2022-06-14 10:29:29] [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@user_id int, @product_id int, @quantity int)
[2022-06-14 10:29:29] begin
[2022-06-14 10:29:29] declare cart_id int;
[2022-06-14 10:29:29] ...' at line 1
```

MariaDB version `10.6.0` if that's relevant.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, got it. It was the `@` signs :)